# Why am I getting "Missing character:" error when using xelatex, xstring, and TikZ?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, xparse, xstring

This question requires a non-default font. I am getting some unusual side-effects from TikZ, xstring, and xelatex. (I normally use a font that may not be shared. I chose THE MORGUE only to replicate the side-effects.)

Setting product to "apple" yields:

> `Missing character: There is no 1 in font [../../Resources/Fonts/MORGUE]/OT:mapping=tex-text;!`

When setting product to "ORANGE"  yields:

> `Missing character: There is no   in font [../../Resources/Fonts/MORGUE]/OT:mapping=tex-text;!
>   Missing character: There is no 1 in font [../../Resources/Fonts/MORGUE]/OT:mapping=tex-text;!`

## Questions

- Where is the `1` coming from?
- Where is the  coming from?
- Why is this happening? *A hint may be that the case affects the outcome.*

## Code

Note to first download MORGUE.ttf into your document (local) folder (I renamed download "THE MORGUE.ttf" to MORGUE.ttf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Path = ./]{MORGUE.ttf}%  http://dl.dafont.com/dl/?f=the_morgue
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Init Vars
\def\thisproduct{???\typeout{Error: Missing thisproduct or invalid product name}}%init

% Product Selector
\NewDocumentCommand{\setproduct}{ m }{%
% Define Products
  \IfEq{#1}{apple}{%
    \def\thisproduct{edition apple}
  }{}%
  \IfEq{#1}{ORANGE}{%
    \def\thisproduct{edition orange}
  }{}%
}%

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\trythis}{ }{% Imitates original definition
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {\thisproduct{}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%

\begin{document}
%\setproduct{apple}
\setproduct{ORANGE}
\trythis
\end{document}
```

---

## Notes

- Font Download: http://dl.dafont.com/dl/?f=the_morgue

Comment: Does it go away if you skip any of those out of three?

Comment: @percusse Since messing with it, I have had inconsistent results. Sometimes the invisible character does not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1 is the page number, and the font apparently doesn't include digits so the warning is expected. (I only get missing character 1 in either case not an invisible character)

Comment: I had an invisible character `6469 7469 6f6e c2a0 6f72 616e 6765 7d0a  dition..orange}.` -> hex c2a0, non-breakable space. This is the culprit. (file encoding utf8). (output from `xxd`)

Comment: This answer does not explain why the page number is typeset. I do not call it explicitly.

Comment: @macmadness86 article class numbers pages by default and you have one page. You need `\pagestyle{empty}`  or similar.

Comment: @macmadness86 perhaps this site stripped the U+00A0 as a space character is used in both the input text and the error message as quoted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

## Supplemental Answer for Mental Health

Finding a non-breakable space can be a pain, because they are invisible. (I used a hexidecimal dump from the unix tool `xxd` to find it the first time). How it got into my code, I do not know. I can not imagine that I accidentally typed `SHIFT CTRL u 0 0 a 0`. It may be from copying text from other sources like PDFs into my source files.

## First ensure all files are utf8 encoded

*or ASCII, since the first binary representations of characters of ascii overlap with utf8 for compatibility.*

### Visual inspection of what you're dealing with

```
find -iname '*.tex'-o -iname '*.sty' -print0 | xargs -0 file -i
```

## Convert improperly encoded files

```
iconv -f (from encoding) -t (to encoding)
```

## Find the little buggers (non-breakable spaces)

```
grep -PIrl "["$'\xc2\xa0'$"]"
```

## Replace them with normal spaces

This seems to break:  `perl -pe 's/\xc2\xa0/\x20/g' $(grep -IPrle "["$'\xc2\xa0'$"]"`

```
perl -i -pe 's/\xc2\xa0/\x20/g' $(find -iname '*.tex' -o -iname '*.sty')
```

---

## Notes

- non-breakable space http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00A0/index.htm
- There is also a fun zero-width non-breakable space http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm